# skype call using username in android

Tags: android, skype

I already know to skype call using phone number but i can't do skype call using skype username please help me thanks

please see my code skype call when using phone number:

```
Intent skype_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
    skype_intent.setClassName("com.skype.raider","com.skype.raider.Main");
    skype_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    skype_intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+91//phone number")); 
    startActivity(skype_intent);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call another skype user like this:

```
Intent skype = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
skype.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + user_name));
startActivity(skype);
```

For video calls:

```
Uri.parse("skype:" + user_name + "?call&video=true")
```