# Place skype video call using tasker

Tags: android, skype, tasker

I'm trying to set up tasker so that it will automatically place a video call with a specific contact when triggered.

So far the most promising thread I've encountered was this one: [skype call using username in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293974/skype-call-using-username-in-android) 
Which isn't about tasker intents, it turns out.

Would it be possible to accomplish this using tasker
And if so, how?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

oh, but it is about intents :)

only those, that are used when writing code.

the ones you need are like:

- **Start a skype audio call**

  - *Action:* `android.intent.action.VIEW`
  - *Data URI:* `skype:CONTACT?call`
- **Start a skype video call**

  - *Action:* `android.intent.action.VIEW`
  - *Data URI:* `skype:CONTACT?call&video=true`
- **Start a skype chat**

  - *Action:* `android.intent.action.VIEW`
  - *Data URI:* `skype:CONTACT?chat`

Answer (score 0):

To realise Tomaskis proposal:

1. Open Tasker
2. Tap on register Task
3. Create new Task
4. First command:

Open Skype app with 'App' - 'Launch App'. Always open with new copy

5. Second command:

Open 'System' - 'Send intent'

6. Add data, as mentioned above. Data URI is data. Replace CONTACT with original Skype user name

Important:

Use original Skype Username. To find: open Skype, goto chat, open chat to whom you want to send the message, tap on picture of user/contact (profile will open), then find skype username.. it can also be something like.. live3c..